# "Error opening terminal: unknown." when trying to run a program inside Eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, linux-mint

I've recently installed Eclipse 3.8 on my Linux Mint PC (I've used it on Ubuntu before without problems) and every time I try to run a C++-program, It just sais "Error opening terminal: unknown." in the Console of Eclipse. Compiling works fine and it also shows the output of gcc correctly.

Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I face the same problem in Lubuntu 13.04 (no problem in Bodhi 2.3.0) I solved this installing "xterm" and doing this in Eclipse IDE:

Run -> Run configurations -> "C/C++ Application" -> *YourProyect* -> Environment -> New... -> TERM=xterm

But then other problem appears, my application uses the console to show some messages, but I also use some SDL "Windows", Eclipse runs fine, but the Windows don't appear. Instead, if I run manually from the terminal, all runs perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

Run -> Run configurations -> "C/C++ Application" -> YourProyect -> Environment -> New... -> DISPLAY=:0.0